# Formatting H1/H2/H3, and a bar of open HTML

Tags: html, css

I am building my first website to learn HTML/CSS/jQuery (and it is hosted on my Raspberry Pi). I have two issues right now: a strip of HTML to the right of the jumbotron/news containers (i made all HTML blue in order for it to be seen). Also, I am trying to get the "hello world" h3 to be snug underneath the h2. I am using placeholder text while I figure everything out. Which CSS properties should I edit to do this?  You can visit the website live at Ericscode.com.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:400,700|Droid+Sans:400,700|Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- CSS from Bootstrap's website -->
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- End Bootstrap head -->
        <!-- My personal CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

</head>
<body>      
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <a href="index.html">Erics Code</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <ul padding-top: 50px;>
                    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                    <li>|</li>
                    <li><a href="#">My Projects</a></li>
                    <li>|<li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
        <h1>My Projects and Portfolio</h1>
        <p>I do internet things</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="news">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>News & Updates</h1>
            <h2>New Personal Website</h2>
            <h3>Hello World</h3>
            <p>This is the first iteration of the website. Expect constant changes and unfinished scripts.</p>


        </div>
    </div>  


    <div class="footer">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <div class="container">
                    <p>Erics Code, personal Internet workspace</p>
                    <p>Hosted on Raspberry Pi</p>
                    <p>~ <a href="contact_me.html">Contact Me</a> ~</P>
                    </div>



                </div>

        </div>
    </div>  

</body>
```

CSS:

```
html {
background-color: blue;

}

.nav {
background-color: #5a5a5a;
height: 70px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 9999;
width: 100%;

}

.nav li{
display: inline-block;
padding: 14px 10px;
text-transform: lowercase;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 18px;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-left: 0px;
font-family: 'Droid Sans';
color: white;
}

.nav a {
color: white;
-o-transition:.5s;
-ms-transition:.5s;
-moz-transition:.5s;
-webkit-transition:.5s;
/* ...and now for the proper property */
transition:.5s;
}

.nav a:hover {
color: #ed8200;
text-decoration: none;
}


.jumbotron {
background-image: url('http://ericscode.com/images/banner1.png');
height: 500px;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-top: 75px;
font-family: 'Droid Sans';
text-align: center;

}
.jumbotron .container {
position: relative;
top: 100px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
color: #ed8200;
font-weight: bold;

}

.jumbotron p {
color: white;
padding-top: 15px;
font-family: 'Droid Sans'
}

.maincontent {
background-color: purple;
font-family: 'Droid Sans';
}

.logo {
font-family: 'Pacifico', sans-serif;
font-size: 50px;
color: white;
padding-top: 0px;
}

.logo a {
color: white;

}

.news {
height: 500px;
}

.news h1{
font-family: 'Droid Sans';
color: #5a5a5a;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 50px;
}

.news h2{
color: #5a5a5a;
}

.news h3{
font-family: 'Orbitron';
color: black;
padding-top: 0px;
color: #ed8200;
font-size: 18px;
}

.news p{
font-family: 'Droid Sans';
}

.footer {
background-color: #5a5a5a;
height: 140px;
color: white;
}

.footer a {
color: white;
}

.footer a:hover {
color: #ed8200;
text-decoration: none;
}
.footer .container {
padding-top: 40px;
}
```

If you see anything else I should change/improve on, let me know! Once I have a proper websites bones setup, I am going to learn more Javascript and implement some smooth transitions using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the `h3` snug, give the `h3` a class:

```
<h3 class="h3">Hello World</h3>
```

And style it:

```
h3.h3{
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

To fix the sideways scrolling, add this to your stylesheet:

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I will give it a try! I appreciate the quick response. The first problem was solved by @Trozdol and had to do with having horizontal scrolling when I didn't intend it to.

Comment: I ended up using your edits and implemented them. Works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what it sounds like, you want the space between your headers to be less. Browsers have a default stylesheet they use to style elements and H1-h6 have a lot of margin on top and bottom.

```
.parent-class h3 {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

I looked at your site and I noticed some horizontal scrolling. This is caused when you have a container with width and margin set to equal a greater value than the available width.

Using the old `margin: 0 auto;` on a container with a width will center that so you don't have to explicitly set the margin.

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="row"> <--- THIS IS THE CAUSE
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <div class="container">
                <p>Erics Code, personal Internet workspace</p>
                <p>Hosted on Raspberry Pi</p>
                <p>~ <a href="contact_me.html">Contact Me</a> ~</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try these out.

Comment: I use `margin: 0 auto` for centering things that cannot be centered with other CSS, not for telling width...lol

Comment: Maybe I wrote wrong. I meant centering something with margin: 0 auto needs to have a width to work.

Comment: I figured it out! I gave the h1/h2/h3/p in the "news" class some margin-top and margin-bottom definitions. What does !important and auto do?

Comment: Ok so I've not really used boot strap but your specific issue with the extra space on the side is happening with the class `.row` inside your footer. Bootstrap is adding a `-15 margin` just remove that class.

Comment: `!important` added to the css gives priority for that specificity. `auto` takes the existing space and kind of divides it up.. depends kind of.